# Query Posts that have Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I'm having trouble querying posts that have multiple tags from a custom taxonomy. For example, if I have a post called "Strawberry Splice," it has the Meal Types (custom taxonomy) "Gluten Free" and "Beverages."

When I filter the posts to look for "Gluten Free," "Strawberry Splice" shows up but when I search for "Beverages," there aren't any results. My query is only looking at the first term.

Take a look at http://jimalie.com.au/recipes/

This is my partial code to generate the custom taxonomy:

```
$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,

    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'meal_types', array('recipes'), $args );
```

This is my code for the query:

```
$mealtype = $_POST['mealtype'];

$args = array('post_type' => 'recipes', 'meal_types' => $mealtype, 'paged' => $paged);
```

I get $mealtype from the dropdown that is dynamically populated:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'meal_types' );
$count = count($terms);
if ($count > 0) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $term->name; ?>" <?php if($_POST['mealtype'] == $term->name) { echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
    <?php }
}
```

My query:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

The whole template's code: http://pastebin.com/5e07FMJm

How do I get it to look at all the terms?

Comment: What is the contents of `$mealtype` and how is it formatted? Also, how are you actully querying the posts - `WP_Query()`, `get_posts()` or `query_posts()`?

Comment: @DavidGard Updated my post with new info. I get $mealtype through the dropdown that is dynamically populated

Answer (score 1):

Got help on Facebook and just needed to change this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $term->name; ?>" <?php if($_POST['mealtype'] == $term->name) { echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
```

to this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" <?php if($_POST['mealtype'] == $term->slug) { echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
```

Comment: Yes, the quick approach that you took (using `{taxonomy_slug} => {term_slug}` instead of `tax_query` uses the slug.